# Visual Studio IDE0059 C# Unnecessary assignment of a value bug?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, roslyn

I have the following C# Code (I reduced it to the bare minimum to simplify it). Visual Studio 2019, .NET Framework 4.7.2.

```
public void Demo()
{
    ReportStart();
    var success = false;
    try
    {
        int no = 1;
        switch (no)
        {
            case 1:
            default:
                break;
        }

        DoSomething();

        success = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        ReportEnd(success);
    }
}
```

From my understanding, there is nothing wrong about it. The function may fail (I don't want to catch it) but before leaving, it will report successful execution to another method. When debugging, it does exactly what it should.

Interestingly, Visual Studio 2019 will report the following:

[image: IDE0059]

When I follow the suggestion by choosing "Remove redundant assignment", it will remove the line `success = true;`, effectively changing the outcome!

Now what is the switch/case for, you'd ask? When removing it, the recommendation disappears:

[image: Animation]

Is there any reason for that, or is it a bug in Visual Studio?

Comment: This is one of those rare times when a gif really adds a lot of value to the question; I wouldn't have believed this until I saw it happen.  Indeed, I can reproduce this behavior locally in VS2019.  I cannot reproduce this in VS2017.  This does look like a defect.

Comment: Recommendation also disappears, when you add a `catch` block. I've observed the same behavior in VS2019 v16.4.5 with .NET Core 3.1

Comment: I guess, these github issues [#39755](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39755) and [#39344](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39344) are about the same (or the similar) issue, it was already fixed in 16.5 version of VS2019

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks, I'm on "Version 16.4.5" indeed, at the time of writing, Version 16.5 is in Preview. These issues are similar indeed.

Comment: Relevant guidance on writing "this is a bug" answers: [How should you answer questions that lead to bug reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132701/how-should-you-answer-questions-that-lead-to-bug-reports/132704#132704)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski when you make your comment regarding the Fix in Version 16.5 an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue with Roslyn and Visual Studio 2019 16.4, please refer to the GitHub issues [#39755](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39755) and [#39344](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39344).

The milestone is set to the version 16.5 Preview 2, so it was already fixed and you can try the preview 2 of 16.5 version or wait for stable one (personally, I'm not using a Preview versions)