# Visual Studio 16.7.6 still falsely reporting IDE0059, despite supposed fixes in 16.5

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

According to the only answer to [Visual Studio IDE0059 C# Unnecessary assignment of a value bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420358/visual-studio-ide0059-c-sharp-unnecessary-assignment-of-a-value-bug), this stupid bug was supposed to have been fixed in Visual Studio 2019 16.5, but I am currently on 16.7.6 and am getting a false positive of this warning in the following code:

```
var r = 5;    // r is actually defined elsewhere
foreach (var num in Enumerable.Range(0, r)) { // IDE0059 raised against num
    DoSomething();    // DoSomething() is also defined elsewhere
}
```

As the comments mentioned, this is just the shortest, simplest example I could come up with to describe the problem; the real code is 564 lines but the problem can be demonstrated in just 4.

Am I getting this warning because I'm not using `num` in the loop body? I know I could easily change the loop to a `for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) { ... }` style one, but why should I have to?! As far as I'm aware, my code is completely valid and compiles fine.

So what gives?? MTIA for any guidance provided :-)

Comment: Other than the line `r = 5;` missing a definition which is flagged in the compiler. I am not understanding what error you would be getting or what you are referring to by a getting a “false positive.” Can you elaborate? Other than that, the code works as expected in my tests.

Comment: side note: using a for loop with an int would require fewer allocations than the call to Enumerable.Range.

Comment: @JohnG Yes, the code works great, and that's the problem (ironically LOL). Visual Studio is falsely telling me that there is a IDE0059 error on `num` when as far as I can tell, there isn't.

Comment: The warning is fairly clear as you are aware, the variable `num` is never used. The compiler is simply flagging something that is odd and superfluous. Its not an error and the code will run, however, from a logical point of view, it makes no since to use a `foreach` loop for a simple sequence loop. In other words, `num` is useless for what the code is doing. The compiler knows this and is hinting to you that you are creating space/resources for no reason. Its just a suggestion, heeding it is your call.

Comment: Yes I'm well aware that I don't **have** to follow MSFT's recommendations on **everything**, but I get easily annoyed by things like this. Anyway you and Jimmy have kindly explained the reasons for this particular instance of the warning, and I must admit they do make sense. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is flagging `num` for exactly the reason you describe - the variable is never read from.  You can try using a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) instead:

```
foreach (var _ in Enumerable.Range(0, r))
```

Comment: Thanks mate, +1! :D

Comment: this takes care of the compiler warning, however, why to make an iterator like this and do nothing with it, there are better ways to do something R times

Comment: LOL @WalterVehoeven, you're the third person to point out my sillyness now, so thanks for making me feel like a script kiddie :P JK, I appreciate the attempt to help me :-)